# How can I remove files that have an unknown number in them?

Tags: python, wildcard, filenames

I have some code that writes out files with names like this:

```
body00123.txt
body00124.txt
body00125.txt

body-1-2126.txt
body-1-2127.txt
body-1-2128.txt

body-3-3129.txt
body-3-3130.txt
body-3-3131.txt
```

Such that the first two numbers in the file can be 'negative', but the last 3 numbers are not.

I have a list such as this:

```
123
127
129
```

And I want to remove all the files that don't end with one of these numbers. An example of the desired leftover files would be like this:

```
body00123.txt

body-1-2127.txt

body-3-3129.txt
```

My code is running in python, so I have tried:

```
if i not in myList:
     os.system('rm body*' + str(i) + '.txt')
```

And this resulted in every file being deleted.

The solution should be such that any .txt file that ends with a number contained by myList should be kept. All other .txt files should be deleted. This is why I'm trying to use a wildcard in my attempt.

Comment: How could `for i not in myList:` even execute? That's a syntax error. Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: My mistake. It should be <if i not in myList>

Comment: What is `i` defined as?

Comment: If `i` is an index into `myList`, then surely i=0, 1, 2, ... ? 
So what you're actually executing is `rm body*0.txt`, `rm body*1.txt`, `rm body*2.txt` etc.
(and what you probably want to actually execute is `'rm body*' + str(myList[i]) + '.txt'`)

Answer (score 0):

Because all the files end in .txt, you can cut that part out and use the `str.endswith()` function. `str.endswith()` accepts a tuple of strings, and sees if your string ends in any of them. As a result, you can do something like this:

```py
all_file_list = [...]
keep_list = [...]

files_to_remove = []

file_to_remove_tup = tuple(files_to_remove)

for name in all_file_list:
    if name[:-4].endswith(file_to_remove_tup)
        files_to_remove.append(name)
        # or os.remove(name)
```

Comment: What is the significance of [-7:-4]?

Comment: You can also do `files_to_remove = [file for file in all_file_list if file[-7:-4] not in keep_list]`. Here, `keep_list` would have to be strings, not ints.

Comment: @FrustratedSnake negative indexing into the string by `[-7:-4]` gets the three characters before the `.txt`, which are the three numbers that identify which files you want to keep

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing

Comment: What if the last 3 numbers could actually also be 4 numbers? Such that there could be files like body001000.txt , and body001005.txt?

Comment: @FrustratedSnake So do you always need to check if the 3- and 4-digit versions exist in the list?

Comment: The only condition is that any .txt file that ends with a number that is contained by myList must be kept. All other .txt files should be deleted.

Comment: @FrustratedSnake I've updated the code to support searching from the end of any length string